# Inverse of Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

We all know that if I give a function, say $e^x$,and I asked you to give me the Taylor expansion of $e^x$,then you would say it is: $$1+x+x^2/2!+...$$,
but what if I gave you $$1+x+x^2/2!+...$$ and I asked you to give me what function it represents, without any prior knowledge like without memorizing it's $e^x$, then how would you know it's $e^x$?

**How can I add a bounty to this question, it's really important for me**

Comment: How do you define $e^x$?

Comment: does it matter?

Comment: Yes, it does. A lot.

Comment: Idk what's your point, but i guess i would define it as a function, idk if that is enough, please elaborate

Comment: As a function? That's all? Are you saying that $e^x$ is just any function whatsoever? If the answer is negative, then *which* function are we talking about?

Comment: okay, well suggest a definition, i guess you can see the answer given by Ishraaq Parvez, that's what i want in the answer,  and i want another way which is more  effective than the one given by Ishraaq.

Comment: One possibility is to define $e^x$ as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$, but then there is nothing to prove. Another possibility is to define the exponential function as the inverse of the logarithm, and to define $\log(x)$ as $\int_1^x\frac{\mathrm dt}t$, and then, yes, something must be proved.

Comment: okay so let's take the log(x) definition. But please note that i'm not trying my question only on $e^x$ but on every function, please see my comment on Ishraaq answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131620/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-elie-makdissi).

Answer (score 0):

\begin{gather*}
f( x) =\sum _{i=0}^{\infty }\frac{x^{i}}{i!}\\
f'( x) =\frac{d}{dx}\sum _{i=0}^{\infty }\frac{x^{i}}{i!} =\sum _{i=0}^{\infty }\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^{i}}{i!}\right) =0+\sum _{i=1}^{\infty }\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^{i}}{i!}\right)\\
\left( as\ \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^{0}}{0!}\right) =0\right)\\
=\sum _{i=1}^{\infty }\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^{i}}{i!}\right) =\sum _{i=1}^{\infty }\frac{i\cdotp x^{i-1}}{i!} =\sum _{i=1}^{\infty }\frac{x^{i-1}}{( i-1) !} =\sum _{i=0}^{\infty }\frac{x^{i}}{i!}\\
Hence,\ f'( x) =f( x)\\
Let\ y=f( x)\\
\frac{dy}{dx} =y\\
\frac{dy}{y} =dx\\
Integrating\ both\ sides,\\
\int \frac{dy}{y} =\int dx\\
\Longrightarrow \ln |y|=x+C\\
\Longrightarrow y=C\cdotp e^{x}\\
At\ x=0,\ y=1,\ so\ C\cdotp 1=1\\
\Longrightarrow C=1\\
Hence\\
f( x) =y=e^{x}
\end{gather*}

Comment: but does this method work for every infinite serie that i give you? I mean i gave $e^x$ as an example in the question to clarify my point, but i think your method works for $e^x$ because it's a simple function, but what about more complex functions? I think it would be hard and unreliable to apply your method

Comment: @ElieMakdissi In general, there is no guarantee that a method can work for all examples. That being said, solving differential equations are generally a good way to get an explicit function from a power series. Like, for example, if you gave me sin(x) or cos(x) too, I might be able to derive the function from its power series.